# Magento 2 moved images to S3 now getting FileSystemException

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, aws, php-7.2, s3

I bought https://magecomp.com/magento-2-amazon-s3.html and it moved my images over to AWS S3 without much issue, the problem now is that when new images are being uploaded to the bucket, they are not displaying in the front end or backend, the images are actually uploaded to S3 but they throw a exception on the backend.

using magento-2.3.2.

Getting exceptions like this:

```
2020-10-23 05:01:46] main.WARNING: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/customer/www/site.com/public_html/m29/pub/media/catalog/product/c/h/chrome-wac-lighting-vanity-lighting-ws-6624-ch-64_1000.jpg {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/customer/www/site.com/public_html/m29/pub/media/catalog/product/c/h/chrome-wac-lighting-vanity-lighting-ws-6624-ch-64_1000.jpg at /home/customer/www/site.com/public_html/m29/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:73)"} []
[2020-10-23 05:01:46] main.WARNING: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/customer/www/site.com/public_html/m29/pub/media/catalog/product/w/s/ws-6624-bn_imro_1_2.jpg {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for 
/public_html/m29/pub/media/catalog/product/w/s/ws-6624-bn_imro_1_2.jpg at /m29/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:73)"} []
[2020-10-23 05:01:46] main.WARNING: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/customer/www/site.com/public_html/m29/pub/media/catalog/product/c/h/chrome-wac-lighting-vanity-lighting-ws-6636-ch-64_1000.jpg {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/customer/www/site.com/public_html/m29/pub/media/catalog/product/c/h/chrome-wac-lighting-vanity-lighting-ws-6636-ch-64_1000.jpg at /public_html/m29/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:73)"} []
```

Any ideas on what I could do about this?

Comment: Should you request help from extension developers?

Comment: I already did. They're not the sharpest tool in the shed.